# convert foreach loop to while loop (for infinite loop in video gallery)

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

The current video gallery circles through set number of videos using the following foreach loop. Can someone help in modifying this so that the video gallery cycles through the videos with endless loop? Perhaps 'while' loop.. How would it change?

```
<?php 
if ( $videos= get_sub_field( 'videos' ) ) : 
?>
    <div class="video-slider ease-right" data-scroll>
<?php 
    foreach ( $videos as $video ) : 
?>
        <div class="video-slider__slide">
<?php 
        if ( $video_url = $video[ 'video' ] ) : 
?>
            <a data-fancybox href="<?php echo $video[ 'video' ]; ?>">
                <?php video_thumb( $video[ 'video' ] ); ?>
            </a>

            <span class="video-caption"><?php echo $video[ 'caption' ]; ?></span>
<?php 
        endif; 
?>
        </div>
<?php 
    endforeach; 
?>
    </div>
<?php 
endif; 
?>
```

Comment: PHP can't do the cycling...all this code you've shown does is output some HTML, which will be static once the page is output to the browser. I notice the "fancybox" mention in the markup...I think that's a JS plugin which provides a gallery using Javascript. To get interactive behaviour such as dynamically cycling through content after your page is loaded, you'd need JavaScript. I'd expect if you consult the documentation for your plugin it will show you what options you can set to control how it cycles through the images. https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/options

Comment: If you have an infinite loop as you are hoping for the the page will never load, the browser will crash and black holes will devour the internet.